# Match truck restriction data to road name/geometry data in Here maps

Tags: here-api

I can get truck restriction data using a request like this: [https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=TRUCK_RESTR_FC3&level=11&tilex=2157&tiley=1620&apiKey={MYKEY}](https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=TRUCK_RESTR_FC3&level=11&tilex=2157&tiley=1620&apiKey=%7BMYKEY%7D)

And road geometry data for same area using this: [https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC3&level=11&tilex=2157&tiley=1620&apiKey={MYKEY}](https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tile.json?layer=ROAD_GEOM_FC3&level=11&tilex=2157&tiley=1620&apiKey=%7BMYKEY%7D)

But when I try to convert or match the data there is a problem. In truck case the link ids are of the form:

`"LINK_IDS":"B51908052"`

whereas in case of road geometry they are of the form:

`"LINK_ID":"51903235"`

Clearly they are different not only in format (since in case of truck they begin with `B`) but also in number itself (since I couldn't find any number `51903235` in the response for truck).

So how can I know which truck restriction is for which road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test and TRUCK_RESTR_FC3 returned 102 lines, while ROAD_GEOM_FC3 returned 1066 lines.
I think the 102 lines are all within 1066 lines and TRUCK_RESTR_FC3 has only LINK_IDS where there are restrictions. If the LINK_ID is not in TRUCK_RESTR_FC3, this LINK_ID is unrestricted.